# AWS Cloudformation create resource conditionally

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I was looking at the Condition Function `Fn::If:` to create or provision a resource only if a condition is evaluated to true. In my case, created a policy if the environment is prod.

```
Parameters:
  Env:
    Description: Environment
    Type: String

Conditions:
  IsProd: !Equals [!Ref Env, 'prod']
```

I know how to do it for a property, but not for the entire resource block.

```
Type: 'AWS::IAM::Policy'
Properties:
  PolicyName: root
  PolicyDocument:
    Version: 2012-10-17
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action: '*'
        Resource: '*'
  Roles:
    - !Ref RootRole
```

Is this something possible?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do it using  [Condition:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html) resource attribute. For example:

```
Resources:

    MyIAMPolicy:

        Condition: IsProd

        Type: 'AWS::IAM::Policy'
        Properties:
          PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: '*'
                Resource: '*'
          Roles:
            - !Ref RootRole
```

More on this can be found here:

- [Conditionally launch AWS CloudFormation resources based on user input](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/conditionally-launch-aws-cloudformation-resources-based-on-user-input/)